# How to programmatically access Sharepoint sites other than root from Office365-REST-Python-Client?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, office365-rest-client

I need to programmatically access my organization's Office 365 Sharepoint. In particular, at the moment I need to be able to upload and download files from specific lists/paths.

I created an Azure AD application using [this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) and granted `Sites.FullControl.All` permission (consent was granted by the admin as well).

[image]

I am using [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) Python library for calling Sharepoint API, which seems to be a well-maintained library and [accepted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/519043/how-can-i-get-access-to-sharepoint-documents-using.html) in the Sharepoint community.

I was able to authenticate as my app using a certificate I created:

```py
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

base_url = 'https://my-company.sharepoint.com/'

cert_auth_data = dict(
    tenant='61ad46cb-b256-451d-9b4c-b592d46a7dc1',
    client_id='b3af34ed-1335-468b-a82b-d0cf6ec79683',
    thumbprint='815B134CD6D15EB0F07D247940AA6EF96263859F',
    cert_path='selfsigncert.pem',
)

ctx = ClientContext(base_url).with_client_certificate(**cert_auth_data)
res = ctx.web.get().execute_query()
print(res.properties['Title'])  # Works
```

Now I need to access a specific site in the portal, and this is where I start having problems. If I put `https://my-company.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite` as URL, I receive the following error:

> ValueError: {'error': 'invalid_resource', 'error_description': 'AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://my-company.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite was not found in the tenant named My Company Limited. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: e8bbbe6c-f5ef-4d6a-8635-0848184e1801\r\nCorrelation ID: f6a57e34-886a-4247-8a4e-194f098876ed\r\nTimestamp: 2022-05-12 02:26:44Z', 'error_codes': [500011], 'timestamp': '2022-05-12 02:26:44Z', 'trace_id': 'e8bbbe6c-f5ef-4d6a-8635-0848184e1801', 'correlation_id': 'f6a57e34-886a-4247-8a4e-194f098876ed', 'error_uri': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011'}

I assumed I can somehow reach the site from the `ClientContext` of the base URL, but I could not figure how to do it and if that is possible at all.

I tried to use `Site` API:

```
site = Site.from_url(site_url)
```

But I see that `Site` lacks `with_client_certificate()` (as opposed to `ClientContext`) and has only `with_credentials()` method. I added such a method similarly to `ClientContext`:

```py
    def with_client_certificate(self, tenant, client_id, thumbprint, cert_path, **kwargs):
        self.context.with_client_certificate(tenant, client_id, thumbprint, cert_path, **kwargs)
        return self
```

However in this case authorization fails with the same error as above.

1. Is my application lacking some permissions? If yes, how to fix that?
2. Am I using the library properly? I failed to find good [examples in their repo](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples) for my case, but other resources suggest that using *site* URL is probably the right way [[1]](https://techwizard.cloud/2020/09/30/get-list-items-sharepoint-online-using-python/), [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/519043/how-can-i-get-access-to-sharepoint-documents-using.html).